# ¿Cómo se puede "desplegar" un select mediante JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, select

Si tengo un select html en un sitio web cargado con varias opciones, ¿Cómo puedo mediante JavaScript hacer que se "despliege" sin necesidad de que el usuario le haga clic para desplegarlo?

```
 <select>
  <option>opcion 1</option>
  <option>opcion 2</option>
  <option>opcion 3</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías simular un evento  click con javascript
Primero  para no abrir  inmediatamente  debes poner un retraso  con `setTimeout` dentro de esta función  colocas  `document.getElementById('id-select').click();`

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Con un select común y corriente no, no se puede. Hay algunos workaround despachando eventos custom, pero no son homogéneos en todos los browsers. De hecho no son homogeneos a través de distintas versiones del mismo browser.

Te sugiero usar una de las muchas librerías que existen para extender la funcionalidad nativa de los select, dado que en ellas el widget JS que sustituye al selector sí puede controlarse netamente por JS. Te dejo un ejemplo usando la popular, simple y elegante librería [Tom Select](https://tom-select.js.org/)

```js
const selectElement = document.querySelector('#select-beast')
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {

  const tomSelect = new TomSelect(selectElement, {
    create: true,
    sortField: {
      field: "text",
      direction: "asc"
    }
  });
  setTimeout(() => tomSelect.open(), 1200)
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tom-select@2.2.2/dist/css/tom-select.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tom-select@2.2.2/dist/js/tom-select.complete.min.js"></script>

<select id="select-beast" placeholder="Select a person..." autocomplete="off">
  <option value="">Select a person...</option>
  <option value="4">Thomas Edison</option>
  <option value="1">Nikola</option>
  <option value="3">Nikola Tesla</option>
  <option value="5">Arnold Schwarzenegger</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el atributo `size` del `select`, el cual, tal y como dice la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select):

> **`size`**
>
> Si el control se presenta como una lista con scroll en caja, este
> atributo representa el numero de filas que la list tendrá visible la
> primera vez. Los navegadores no están requeridos a presentar un
> elemento select como una lista con escroll en caja. El valor por
> defecto es cero.

Por ejemplo:

```html
<select name="sometext" size="7">
  <option>opción 1</option>
  <option>opción 2</option>
  <option>opción 3</option>
  <option>opción 4</option>
  <option>opción 5</option>
  <option>opción 6</option>
  <option>opción 7</option>
</select>
```

Imaginemos que sólo quieres mostrar las primeras tres opciones:

```html
<select name="sometext" size="3">
  <option>opción 1</option>
  <option>opción 2</option>
  <option>opción 3</option>
  <option>opción 4</option>
  <option>opción 5</option>
  <option>opción 6</option>
  <option>opción 7</option>
</select>
```

### Otras alternativas

Pero considera que podría haber otros elementos más naturales, interesantes y fáciles de usar, tales como `checkbox` o `radio`. Como los `option` de un `select`, ambos tiene un atributo `value`, admiten también atributos `data-*` y puedes hacer cualquier cosa con ellos de forma programática, como determinar cuáles han sido marcados o no, escuchar los cambios, etc.

#### `checkbox`

Con **`checkbox`** puedes seleccionar varios elementos:

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" value="1" />Opción 1</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" value="2" />Opción 2</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" value="3" />Opción 3</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" value="4" />Opción 4</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" value="5" />Opción 5</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" value="6" />Opción 6</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" value="7" />Opción 7</label><br />
```

#### `radio`

Con **`radio`** puedes seleccionar, sólo uno, si los radio tienen el mismo `name`, así, puedes poner un `name` distinto para crear grupos de radio por ejemplo:

```html
<h2>Grupo A</h2>
<p>Sólo puedes seleccionar uno de este grupo</p>
<label><input type="radio" name="grupo-a" value="1" />Opción 1</label><br />
<label><input type="radio" name="grupo-a" value="2" />Opción 2</label><br />
<label><input type="radio" name="grupo-a" value="3" />Opción 3</label><br />
<label><input type="radio" name="grupo-a" value="4" />Opción 4</label><br />

<hr />
<h2>Grupo B</h2>
<p>Sólo puedes seleccionar uno de este grupo</p>

<label><input type="radio" name="grupo-b" value="5" />Opción 5</label><br />
<label><input type="radio" name="grupo-b" value="6" />Opción 6</label><br />
<label><input type="radio" name="grupo-b" value="7" />Opción 7</label><br />
```

Pensando en el usuario, puede que estas dos últimas opciones sean más cómodas, para lo que pareces pretender aquí, claro está, si no hablamos de una gran cantidad de opciones.